# Getting all the lines containing a specific string from a Text File in windows

Tags: windows, copy

I have a text file on my windows machine. I have a matching string. Say "check_time".

I need to get all the lines which have these strings and copy them in a separate file. Only the lines matching this string should be copied. Since, it is a huge log file, searching with CTRL + F is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check out built-in **findstr** command.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr

Answer (score 0):

```
type "source.txt" | findstr "check_time" > result.txt
```

is there possible to replace the string "check_time" with a file containing several strings (one on each line)?
and parse "source.txt" for each line in "check_time.txt" file?